# How do I get rid of this chord line along the x-axis when importing an airfoil into XFLR5?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing, airfoil, airplane, cfd

Whenever I try to import an airfoil into XFLR5, I always notice the chord centerline along the x-axis as you can see in the picture.

Is there a way to somehow get rid of this line?

I'd be thankful for any type of advice since this line is making my airfoil analysis unusable at the moment.

[image: Weird line along airfoil]

Comment: Indeed, I mean the centreline of the chord. I was able to get rid of this line using Selig airfoil data instead of lednicer airfoil data. 

But what causes that Lednicer airfoil data are basically useless for importing an airfoil into XFLR5? Is this phanomena only occurring within XFLR5?

Comment: However, when running an airfoil analysis with this ''weird'' centerline that came with the airfoil data the results in XFLR5 are wrong and not usable. Most likely due to xflr5 assuming that all panels are interacting with the free stream in some way.

Comment: if you found the answer provided by Rob answered your question, you can click the check mark next to it to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely are importing the points with the wrong order.

Usually programs are looking for points to start at the TE and go clockwise along the lower surface to the LE and then back to the TE along the upper surface.

However, if you did lower surface then upper surface, both TE to LE, then there might be a line connecting the lower LE to the upper TE like you see here.